# Can't find openjdk's jre? No Java plugin in Chrome web browser

Tags: google-chrome

I have recently installed `openjdk` just to try out writing some java application

```
$ dpkg -l | grep jdk
ii  openjdk-7-jdk                          7u7-2.3.2a-0ubuntu0.12.04.1             OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
ii  openjdk-7-jre                          7u7-2.3.2a-0ubuntu0.12.04.1             OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-7-jre-headless                 7u7-2.3.2a-0ubuntu0.12.04.1             OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
ii  openjdk-7-jre-lib                      7u7-2.3.2a-0ubuntu0.12.04.1             OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
```

That's what I have on my system.

Although I have all this installed when in Chrome I go to a website which needs `jre` it can't find it.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Which website was that?

Comment: Is `icedtea-7-plugin`installed? If not install using command line or Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: @user68186 `icedtea-7-plugin` wasn't installed. When I installed it now java on websites works fine. You can post this as an answer so that I can accept it ;)